# In spring security application with jdbc-user-service authentication, with multi users login

Tags: spring-security, session-cookies

If user A has already logged in to the application and then user B logs in to the same application, on the same browser in different tabs/ windows (shares same cookies) user A's session is being overridden by user B's :(

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-session/ "Spring Session supports managing multiple users' sessions in a single browser instance"

Comment: But I have already integrated spring-security in my application and using session support given by that
       <http use-expressions="true" create-session="ifRequired" >
<session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-authentication-error-url="/sessionExpired" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
            <concurrency-control  max-sessions="10"  expired-url="/sessionExpired" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
        </session-management>

Comment: After B logs in, even on A's page it is showing B's name
${pageContext.request.userPrincipal.name} Iam calling this in jsp to show the name, 
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal() to retrieve the user name in controller